# KineticJS Hit Region To Image Collision Detection

Tags: collision-detection, kineticjs

Is there any way to detect whether a shape or point is in the image hit region? The event handling 'on' function seems to only deal with mouse/touch events.

If there isn't, then what would be the best way of getting collision boundaries on a map. The way I was planning on doing it, was to have the map and a wallMap underneath it, creating a hit region with the wallMap and detecting whether the character had hit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep, just use the getPointerPosition() method to get the mouse/touch position, and then use the intersects() method to test for an intersection:

http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Stage.html#getpointerposition
http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#intersects

Comment: The question was to detect "shape or point" hit. The answer is again about mouse hit. The comment to the answer is "exactly what I needed".
I didn't understand in what language you are talking.